# How to set PDFPageOverlayViewProvider for PDFView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-pdfkit

[UPDATED] I'm trying to set a `pageOverlayViewProvider` for a `PDFView` and it does not work as expected. `PDFPageOverlayViewProvider` methods are not being called, `PDFViewDelegate` methods are working fine.

```
struct ReaderView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    public typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    
    let url: URL
    let document: PDFDocument
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        self.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)!
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        
        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.delegate = context.coordinator
        pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = context.coordinator
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        document.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

```
extension ReaderView {
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PDFPageOverlayViewProvider, PDFViewDelegate, PDFDocumentDelegate {
        
        func pdfView(_ view: PDFView, overlayViewFor page: PDFPage) -> UIView? {
            return UIView(frame: .zero)
        }
        
        func pdfView(_ pdfView: PDFView, willDisplayOverlayView overlayView: UIView, for page: PDFPage) { 
        }
        
        func pdfView(_ pdfView: PDFView, willEndDisplayingOverlayView overlayView: UIView, for page: PDFPage) { 
        }
        
        func pdfViewWillClick(onLink sender: PDFView, with url: URL) {
        }
        
        func didMatchString(_ instance: PDFSelection) {
        }

}
```

Comment: That isn't how you create a Coordinator in a `UIViewRepresentable` -- look into the `makeCoordinator` function

Comment: @jnpdx thanks! I fixed my question. Still can't make it work. Is setting pageOverlayViewProvider to PDFView working for you?

Comment: I’m having exactly the same problem in trying to use PDFPageOverlayViewProvider with NSViewRepresentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `pageOverlayViewProvider` to work with `PDFView`, it seems that setting this instance property must be done *before* associating a PDF document with `PDFView`.

In using `UIViewRepresentable`, the following ought to work when making the `PDFView` with the `makeUIView` function:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.delegate = context.coordinator
    pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = context.coordinator
    pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
    pdfView.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    pdfView.document = document
    document.delegate = context.coordinator

    return pdfView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this issue as well, based on [omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17563212/omar)'s answer, here's what I've added to my `PDFView` subclass:

```swift
private var _document: PDFDocument?
    
public override var pageOverlayViewProvider: PDFPageOverlayViewProvider? {
    willSet {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281656
        _document = document
        document = nil
    }
    didSet {
        document = _document
    }
}
```