# PKCanvas is not drawable as a subview of PDFKit OverlayView

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, pdfkit, pencilkit

I want to overlay pencil kit canvases automatically on PDFView with the new PDFKit OverlayProvider Protocol in iPad OS 16.
I added PKCanvas view as a subview of OverlayView, which is UIView, for PDFKit. I succeed in displaying and deleting overlay views based on the OverlayViewProvider protocol.
[Setup the pdfview in overlay provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281656/how-to-set-pdfpageoverlayviewprovider-for-pdfview)

The canvases are displayed as it supposed to be, however, the pencil interaction is not activated. Instead, only the PDF UI scroll view gesture is activated. Should I drop PDF views' gestures?

PDFView for Swift UI

```
struct PDFKitViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let pdfDocument: PDFDocument
    let pdfView:PDFView
    
    
    init(showing pdfDoc: PDFDocument, pdfView:PDFView) {
        self.pdfDocument = pdfDoc
        self.pdfView = pdfView
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        pdfView.autoScales = false
        
        pdfView.delegate = context.coordinator
        pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = context.coordinator
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.04, alpha: 0.2)
        
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator()-> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}
```

Coordinator code

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, PDFPageOverlayViewProvider, PDFViewDelegate, PDFDocumentDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, PKCanvasViewDelegate, PKToolPickerObserver {
    
    var pageToViewMapping = [PDFPage: CustomUIView]()
    
    func pdfView(_ view: PDFView, overlayViewFor page: PDFPage) -> UIView? {
        var resultView:CustomUIView  = CustomUIView()
        
        if let overlayView = pageToViewMapping[page] {

        var canvas = overlayView.viewWithTag((Int(page.label!)!))
            canvas?.becomeFirstResponder()
            resultView = overlayView
        } else {
            let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.init()
            var canvasView = PKCanvasView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
            
            resultView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
            canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput

            canvasView.backgroundColor = .yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

            resultView.frame = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)

            toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
            toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
            canvasView.delegate = resultView
            canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()            
            canvasView.tag = Int(page.label!)!
            resultView.addSubview(canvasView)
            pageToViewMapping[page] = resultView
        }
        
        let page = MyPDFPage(page:page)
        return resultView
    }
    
    func pdfView(_ pdfView: PDFView, willDisplayOverlayView overlayView: UIView, for page: PDFPage){                
    // Overlay view will display
    }
    
    func pdfView(_ pdfView: PDFView, willEndDisplayingOverlayView overlayView: UIView, for page: PDFPage){
    // Overlay view would be disappear
    }
    
}
```

In the 2022 WWDC PDFKit video - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10089/ - it would be achievable with less than 30 lines of code. So I use the code snippet and check the basic mechanism. But can not draw on canvas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960885/pdfkit-pdfpageoverlayviewprovider-with-pkcanvasview-is-not-forwarding-touch-ev Looks like the same issue.

Comment: Additionally, PDFView should follow those conditions
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
pdfView.usePageViewController(false)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why drawing gestures and scrolling gestures are having conflict was configuration of PDF View.

pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
pdfView.usePageViewController(false)

Then you should set isUserInteractionEnabled as true on overlay view install.

See [PDFKit - PDFPageOverlayViewProvider with PKCanvasView is not forwarding Touch events - WWDC22 Session 10089](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960885/pdfkit-pdfpageoverlayviewprovider-with-pkcanvasview-is-not-forwarding-touch-ev)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set `isInMarkupMode` on the `PDFView` instance to `true`, so it changes how hit testing works.